# General notion of memory for a computational model

Tags: computation-models, memory-management

I have just started studying Michael Sipser's Theory of Computation, studying various computational models such as FAs, PDAs et cetera.

In the book, the term "memory" was often used,as in the case of FAs, it was taken to be the number of states, or for PDAs, the length of the stack, which is infinite,a hint as to why PDAs also accept Context-Free non-regular languages.

I wonder how this Notion of memory is thought of;how can we effectively decide for any computational model,its corresponding "memory"  (if even there is one?)